# Updating Document with Embedded Document in Mongoose not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collections called `classroom` which already have a record. I want to update the document with Embedded Document called `timetable`. When i perform update operation, this a displayed in console `{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }`. And document are not updating.

**Classroom Schema**

```
var ClassroomSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({


    classroom_name: {
        type:String,
        required:true,
        unique: true,
    },

    classroom_blok:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },

    classroom_floor: {
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },



    timetable: 
    {
        timeslot: {
            required: true, 
            'type': String,
        },

        subject :{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Subject'
        },

        teacher :{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Teacher'   
        },

        day :{
            type:String, 
            required: true, 
        },

        year :{
            type:String, 
            required: true, 
        },

        session :{
            type:String,
            required:true,
        }
    }





});
```

**Update Operation**

```
router.post('/timetable_morning', function (req, res, next) {
  if (
    req.body.teacher &&
    req.body.timeslot,
    req.body.subject,
    req.body.classroom,
    req.body.session,
    req.body.day) {

    var timetableData = {
      teacher: req.body.teacher,
      timeslot: req.body.timeslot,
      subject: req.body.subject,
      classroom:  req.body.classroom,
      year: currentYear,
      day: req.body.day,
      session: req.body.session
    }

    //use schema.create to insert data into the db
        var timetableData1 = {
          teacher: req.body.teacher,
          timeslot: req.body.timeslot,
          subject: req.body.subject,
          classroom:  req.body.classroom,
          year: currentYear,
          day: req.body.day,
          session: req.body.session
        }

        Classroom.updateOne({_id:req.body.classroom},timetableData1,function(err,classroom){
          if(!err){
            console.log(classroom);
            return res.redirect('/timetable');
          }
        });

  } else {
    var err = new Error('All fields have to be filled out');
    err.status = 400;
    return next(err);

  }

});
```

**Example of Existing Document**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ee3943833325c210c9a7fee"),
    "classroom_name" : "6 Musytari",
    "classroom_blok" : "A",
    "classroom_floor" : "2",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Comment: Can you try `_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.classroom)` ?

Comment: You have to delete all entries from the collection `Classroom`, you cannot update the same document (that was created with old schema) with added fields (that has new schema defined)!

Answer (score 0):

your handler function can be like this

```
router.post('/timetable_morning/:classroom_id', function (req, res, next) {
let dataObj = {
    subject: req.body.subject,
    teacher: req.body.teacher,
    timeslot: req.body.timeslot,
    year: currentYear,
    day: req.body.day,
    session: req.body.session
}
db['Classroom'].updateOne({_id: req.params.classroom_id}, {timetable: dataObj}).then(data => {
    if (data.nModified !== 0) {
        console.log("updated successfully")
    } else {
        console.log("Something went wrong")
    }
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})})
```

**Note**

**please make a note here the field classroom_id should be none other then the mongodb ObjectID that you will pass as a param to your route handler function**

I also noticed that your payload is having one more field classroom while updating the document which is causing the issues because you are trying to update the value which the timetable embedded document does not have.